# Finding the count of triangles in a 4 vertices complete graph after coin toss/erasure

Tags: probability

Consider a complete graph with 4 vertices (i.e., every two vertices are
connected by an edge). For each of the 6 edges we toss a coin, and if heads occur, then we erase the edge. Let X be the number of triangles in the graph. Find E(X).

How should I even approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(0 edges removed) = 1/(2^6) = 1/64.
Number of triangles = 4.

P(1 edge removed) = 6/64.
Number of triangles = 2.

P(2 edges removed) = 15/64 (from 6 choose 2).
Number of triangles (if they share a vertex) = 1.
P(share vertex) = 12/15 (12 combinations from the 15 pairs of edges).
Number of triangles (if they don't share a vertex) = 0.

P(3 edges removed) = 20/64.
Number of triangles (if they all shared 1 vertex) = 1.
P(share vertex) = 4/20 (4 combinations from the 20 triplets of edges).
Otherwise = 0.

E(number of triangles) = 4*1/64 + 2*6/64 + 1*12/15*15/64 + 1*4/20*20/64 = 32/64.

E(number of triangles) = 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Each potential triangle has probability $\frac{1}{8}$ of being an actual triangle after the flips, so contributes $\frac{1}{8}$ to the expected number of triangles.

There are $\binom{4}{3}$ potential triangles.

Adding the expectations for each potential triangle, it follows that the expected number of triangles is 
$${\small{\binom{4}{3}}}\left({\small{\frac{1}{8}}}\right)={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Comment: can you please explain how you got the probability 1/8 for each potential triangle? and why there are 4 choose 3 potential triangles, when there are 4 triangles in the original graph(small size) and 4 more triangles (with two smaller in each) ?

Comment: Firstly, in a complete graph with $4$ vertices, any $3$ vertices determine a triangle. There are no other triangles (i.e., no "smaller triangles"). So there are only $4$ triangles before the flips.

Comment: Each potential triangle has $3$ edges, so the probability that it remains a triangle after the flips is 
$$\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)^3 = {\small{\frac{1}{8}}}$$

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this and this definitely cleared things up~

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematica to demonstrate the problem.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Define vertices*)vertices = {1, 2, 3, 4};

(*Generate all possible edges*)
possibleEdges = 
  Subsets[UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[vertices, {2}], {0, 6}];

(*Generate all graphs*)
graphs = Graph[vertices, #, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
     ImagePadding -> 10] & /@ possibleEdges;

2^Binomial[4, 2] == Length[graphs] (* 64 *)

(*Display graphs*)
Grid[Partition[graphs, 8], Frame -> All];

count3Cycles[g_Graph] := Tr[MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3]]/6;
counter = count3Cycles /@ graphs
Tally[counter] (* {{0, 41}, {1, 16}, {2, 6}, {4, 1}} *)
Mean[counter]   (*1/2*)
Variance[counter]   (* 40/63 *)
```

---

FYI:

Let's denote $c_k$ as count of $k$-cycles in one graph. According to [this Wolfram MathWorld Page](https://This%20Wolfram%20MathWorld%20page), Harary and Manvel (1972) gave the following closed forms for small $k$:

$$
c_3= \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}^3)}{6}
\\
\cdots
$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is the adjancency matrix of the graph.